# Object.assign on two objects with same key but array as a property (redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

reducer:

```
export default function filterReducer(state=InitialState.filters, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'removeFilter':
                switch(action.filter){
                    case 'sources':
                        Object.assign({}, 
                        state, 
                        {
                         sources=state.sources.filter( 
                         source => source==action.filter.sources?false:true
                             )
                          }
                       )
                    default:return state
                }

InitialState.filters=
    filters: {
        sources: ['dasda', 'asd','asdk'],
        years: {from:null, to:null},
        price: {from:null, to:null},
        mileage:{from:null, to:null},
        colors:['white', 'black', 'red', 'grey', 'blue', 'silver']
    }
```

State is not getting updated, and I am sure it is something to do with an array being the property and merging it. From the `Object.assign` documentation object keys with same properties get replaced with the properties in the latest object in the `parameters/arguments.`

Comment: If you're looking to assign to state, pass state as the first argument to `Object.assign()`. As you have it, `state` does not get changed because it is not listed as the target of Object.assign - it is listed as a source.

Comment: You do NOT want to "assign to state" in a reducer - that's a direct mutation, and will break things.  The given example looks roughly valid as-is.  @Zeeshan Hassan, can you clarify what the problem is?  It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, and what is happening instead.

Comment: i didnt put enough code for the context, sorry, see edit

Comment: i used combine reducers later , hence the export and partial passing of initial state

Comment: if `action.filter` is a primitive string `"sources"`, then it is not an object with a `sources` property.

Comment: switch(Object.keys(action.filter)[0]), action.filter={sources:['asda', 'xxx']}

Comment: still a no go,it updates state but nothing happens. Its definitely an issue in Object.assign

Comment: `sources=state.sources.filter( 
                         source => source==action.filter.sources?false:true
                             )` should be `sources: state.sources.filter( 
                         source => source==action.filter.sources?false:true
                             )`  since sources is object key

Comment: still not working, i had changed this a minute ago.

Comment: When the case is `sources`, you are not returning anything, just assigning a new object with some state info, but that statements lacks a `return` statement, hence you fall through to the default state

Comment: for now im just mutating state, because according to docs it only causes issues if components need to be re-rendered based on state change. I'm using this state to send data for a filter query so not an issue for this use case I think.unless there is some other caveat im missing. 
http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html#why-is-immutability-required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement lacks a return, or doesn't do anything in your source code, but to return the default state

```
switch(action.filter){
    case 'sources':
        Object.assign({}, 
            state, 
            {
            sources=state.sources.filter( 
                source => source==action.filter.sources?false:true
            )
            }
        )
    default:return state
}
```

What is happening here is that you created a new object, assigned state to it, and then nothing. The switch statement ends with returning the default state. You are lacking the `return` before `Object.assign()`